# Can I easily override the translation of a word in my Concrete 5.7 theme?

Tags: concrete5, concrete5-5.7

Is there a way to easily override the translation of a word or phrase as produced by the `t()` function throughout the Concrete5 settings pages/dashboard, without altering core files?

For example, if several core files use this code:

```
<?= t('Empty Auto-Nav Block.') ?>
```

Can I somehow override this and specify my own translation without producing another whole language file?

Comment: I don't think this is possible without overriding the whole language file into `/application/languages`

Answer (score 1):

This does not appear to be easily possible.

Concrete 5.7 uses [Zend Translate](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.9/en/zend.translate.html), and others on S.O. have asked about creating overrides for this (see [*override gettext .mo files*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253985/override-gettext-mo-files)).

If you only need to override a few words from the default US language, you can:

1. Create a custom MO file using a tool such as [POEditor.com](https://poeditor.com), including just the words/terms you want to override
2. Save the `.mo` file to `/application/languages/[LANGUAGE-CODE]/LC_MESSAGES/`
3. Enable your new language file via *C5 Dashboard > Settings > Basics > Languages*

However if you need to override words from another language, it looks like you might have to create your own custom PO/MO files that contains the entire dictionary. You can probably import an existing one from the [official c5 translations repository](https://github.com/concrete5/concrete5-translations/) on Github.

This appears to be a major limitation of the Zend Translate library.